# Values for txid and vout for create a coinbase transaction

Tags: coinbase-transaction, transaction-id, createrawtransaction

I want create a coinbase transaction to go with a new block minned by my program. I am creating it with the json-rpc command `createrawtransaction`. What's the values for `txid` and `vout` in this case?

Comment: what the right way? beginner here, and don't found this anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

The coinbase transaction contains a single input, which has  `txid` set to `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` and `vout` set to `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: with this values, I got a Parse error as response. the json string I using is: `{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method":"createrawtransaction", "params":[{"txid":"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","vout":0xFFFFFFFF}]`. I also try with `"vout":"0xFFFFFFFF"`

Comment: @KleberMota You cannot enter a hex number or string for `vout`. That is invalid JSON.